# Sorting based on multiple condition and using other list in java

Tags: java, sorting, conditional-statements

I have

```
class cluster{
    string name;
    string id;
    list<Feature> flist;
}

class Feature{
    string name;
    string id;
}
```

cluster can have multiple lists of `Feature`

Now I have list of `Feature` say `list<Feature> list={f1,f2,f3,f4}` , thease `Feature` objects can be spread across different `cluster` objects and some might be not part of any `cluster`.

I have list of cluster and I have to sort based on the list of `Feature` I have.

```
input:
cluster1-f2,f6,f7
cluster2-f3,f4,f5
cluster3-f9,f8
cluster4-f1,f10
cluster5-f11,f12



 output:
 cluster4-f1,f10
 cluster1-f2,f6,f7
 cluster2-f3,f4,f5
 cluster3-f9,f8
 cluster5-f11,f12
```

Please help me to sort `cluster` objects based on the given `Feature` list.

Comment: This isn't a coding-writing service, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Java expert, but below is how I sort custom object arrays.  In my example, I have an array of Card objects and can call `sortByInterval` to sort the array (without returning a new array).  In the `Comparator` class you return either -1, 1 or 0 so you can add whatever code you need to compare.

```
public static void sortByInterval (ArrayList<Card> array) {
    Collections.sort(array, new SortByIntervalComparator());
}

private static class SortByIntervalComparator implements Comparator<Card> {
    public int compare(Card card1, Card card2) {

        if (...) return -1      // -1: obj1 first
        else if (...) return 1; // 1: obj2 first
        else return 0;      // equal sort
    }
}
```

Comment: using comperator is the proper way to set the order!